# If $f$ is holomorphic and satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq \exp[(\Re z)^2 - (\Im z)^2]$, then $f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is holomorphic and satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq \exp[(\Re z)^2 - (\Im z)^2]$, then $f=0$

I thought about using uniqueness, though I have a problem showing that I have a limit point of $0$.
I can show that I have a limit point of epsilon for any epsilon that I want, but I cannot show that there is even a single $z f(z)=0$ beside $z=0$.

Comment: look up the Phragmen-Lindelof principle.

Comment: is there a more basic approach @dezdichado?

Comment: Note that $(\Re z)^2 - (\Im z)^2 = \Re (z^2)$, and $e^{\Re w} = \lvert e^w\rvert$.

Comment: so all I need to do is to use Schwartz lemma? @DanielFischer

Comment: Not even that (but that should be Schwarz, as in Hermann Amandus, not Schwartz as in Laurent). Just Liouville.

Comment: for Liouville I need a constant bound.

Comment: I can divide by $e^w$ but I will get that f is bounded by $e^w$

Comment: ohhh the constant must be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complete the story in the comments, one has $$\left|\frac{f(z)}{e^{z^2}}\right|\leq e^{\mathfrak{(R\mathrm z)^{2}-(\mathfrak{I}\mathrm{z})^{2}}}\cdot \frac 1{\left|e^{z^2}\right|}=e^{\mathfrak{R}(z^2)}\cdot\frac 1{e^{\mathfrak{R}(z^2)}}=1,$$ which implies $$\frac{f(z)}{e^{z^2}}=C,$$ by Liouville. Now $f(0)=0$ shows that $C=0.$ It follows that $f(z)=0.$ QED

Answer (score -1):

Actually I understood it quite differently :

$\begin{array}{c}
|f(z)|\leq e^{(\Re z)^{2}-(\Im z)^{2}}=e^{\Re z^{2}}=|e^{z^{2}}|\\
0\leq\frac{|f(z)|}{|e^{z^{2}}|}\leq1
\end{array}$

now by Liouville:

$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{|f(z)|}{|e^{z^{2}}|}=c\\
f(z)=c|e^{z^{2}}|\\
0=f(0)=c\Rightarrow f(z)=0
\end{array}$

Comment: But this does not quite work: First of all, $e^{{\mathfrak R}z^2}\neq e^{|z^2|}.$ Secondly, $e^{|z^2|}$ is not holomorphic. After replacing $e^{|z^2|}$ by $|e^{z^2}|$, the argument will be essentially the same (cf. Daniel Fisher's comments).

Comment: @Pythagoras $(\Re z)^2 - (\Im z)^2 = \Re (z^2)$,$e^{\Re w} = \lvert e^w\rvert$? isn't it?

Comment: What you wrote in the comment is correct, but in your answer, the absolute value signs are misplaced.

Comment: you don't agree that $e^{\Re {z}^2} = \lvert e^{z^2}\rvert$

Comment: Now you fixed it, but the last but one line is still not making sense, since $|e^{z^2}|$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: if I'll replace abs, with Re it will make sense?